# Sum of generalized hypergeometric functions vanishing

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-function

I am currently studying the periods of the quintic Calabi-Yau. These are given by solutions to PF operators, which can be expressed in terms of hypergeometric functions. By geometric reasons, a certain combination of hypergeometric functions has to vanish, namely

$2\frac{ \, _4F_3\left(\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{5};\frac{2}{5},\frac{3}{5},\frac{4}{5};1\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^5}-10\frac{ \,
   _4F_3\left(\frac{2}{5},\frac{2}{5},\frac{2}{5},\frac{2}{5};\frac{3}{5},\frac{4}{5},\frac{6}{5};1\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^5}+25\frac{ \,
   _4F_3\left(\frac{3}{5},\frac{3}{5},\frac{3}{5},\frac{3}{5};\frac{4}{5},\frac{6}{5},\frac{7}{5};1\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^5}-\frac{125}{3}\frac{ \,
   _4F_3\left(\frac{4}{5},\frac{4}{5},\frac{4}{5},\frac{4}{5};\frac{6}{5},\frac{7}{5},\frac{8}{5};1\right)}{ \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^5}=0$

Numerically one can check that this is indeed correct. Such points exist not only for the quintic, but any CY 3-fold. Now I am wondering

1. Is there a direct way to prove the vanishing of the combination?
2. Does an identity exist which generalizes this, i.e. linear combinations of generalized hypergeometric $_4F_3$ functions of the same differential operator that vanish at special rational arguments? This would be useful to understand the general case.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Maybe start by looking [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric4F3/03/02/). You might find one that helps